# Which champions work best with Zeke's Harbinger?

Tags: league-of-legends

When and with which champions should I buy Zeke's Harbinger?  Is it a bad idea if i'm playing as Soraka or Sona to build it? Should I build it if my lane/team is winning or losing?

I understand it's situational, but give me an example when to buy it and when not to.

Comment: Hi Haezard! I understand your frustration, but I highly recommend you check your your previous question first. This question has the same issues as the previous one. (unclear title for example, passive-aggressive tone in the body)  - Be mindful that you're not only looking for answers, but your question is also what someone else is going to be looking for! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much never. Zeke's is a really bad item in the current meta. I'll take your two supports as examples.

Soraka is all about movement speed and sustain. She wants to be everywhere providing healing and silences. Zeke's does not bring any of this to the fight.

Sona is very similar. She wants to be providing the movement speed and starting fights with her ultimate. Zeke's does not bring any of this to the fight either.

I would only ever build this item if your adc is Twitch and that's about it. He can come out of the shadows and really use the crit with his ultimate.

Comment: I tried it with an ashe adc, unfortunately you can't get over 100% crit :(

Comment: Would very much like to dispute this answer.  I consider much of it to just be quite incorrect, considering the two examples given were exmaples were the item would be rather useless
http://www.lolking.net/items/3050?region=all&map=sr&queue=1x1&league=platinum#statistics
Statistics show that Zekes herald is quite a useful item, hovering at around a 60% winrate when built on some supports in the Plat level of play.

Comment: Many league players refuse to trust statistics, but even so, there are some supports where zekes are ideal
- Thresh gains much wanted stats from Zekes (Mana, AP and armour), and the 50% additional crit chance giving close to 100% crit in fights to your ADC is incredibly good
Also works Janna, Nami and Bard

Comment: @BritishFerret you should flesh that out into an answer :)

Comment: @Robotnik Ha...ha :)

Comment: @BritishFerret I disagree. Winrates with such a low popularity won't give you enough information. You can see that Zeke's had a 0% winrate for an entire day. That's astounding. It's also not a good item for the champions that are listed in the question, which is why I mentioned those specific ones.

Comment: 0% winrate is clearly down to a server error of somesort. It is ridiculous to assume that for a day, nobody won building Zeke's. The question also asked "which champions could build it on?", so I suggested some.

Answer (score 2):

Like most items in League, Zeke's Harbinger is **Situational**. You should only really build it when *you* think it's good to be built.

**What is Zeke's and why is it good?**

Zeke's gives:

> +250 Mana
> +30 Armor
> +50 Ability Power
> +10% Cooldown Reduction

and

> UNIQUE Active - Conduit: Bind to target ally (60 second cooldown).
>
> UNIQUE Passive: When within 1000 units of each other, you and your
> ally generate Charges. Attacking or casting spells generates extra
> Charges. At 100 Charges, causing damage consumes them, increasing your
> and your ally's Ability Power by 20% and Critical Strike Chance by 50%
> for 8 seconds.

Firstly, the stats you get from the item are very good stats for many supports. Zeke's gives supports a little bit of armour (which in most builds, support's don't get at all) to protect them from enemy Auto-attacks. It also gives a fair amount of mana and AP, and 10% CDR, which makes it quite viable to replace another item on a support.
Secondly, the passive gives you and your ADC +50% crit chance, and 20%+ AP, but you or your ADC rather should keep an eye on the charges (Don't waste them for farming when a teamfight is about to happen). In the late game, a usual ADC build gives an ADC around 50% crit.

Let's use this as an example:

[image: A jinx build]

Hurricane and RFC give 30% crit each, so in total, this build has 60% crit. Meaning most of the time, an autoattack would be a crit. However, 40% of the time, the AA will not crit and only do 100% damage, vs. the 250% damage you can get with an Infinity edge in the build. Having zeke's active means that your ADC can do *250% damage every attack for 8 seconds*, which is massive.

**Which champions?**

Herald works well on Champions that

1. Benefit from the stats
2. Can stick close to and help their ADC
   survive

Zekes can be a good buy on champions like Soraka and Sona. Both of these supports excel at sticking by their ADC, with Sona's movespeed buff, and Soraka's movespeed buff towards damaged allies. Both of these ADCs benefit from *all* these stats. This allows them to stick by their ADC in a teamfight, and help them buy charges, before allowing them to do 250% damage for 8 seconds, and heavily damage the enemy's front or backline.

**Who is Zekes bad on?**
Zeke's provides good stats for 'mage like' supports, but is quite lacklustre for Tank supports, it probably shouldn't be built on supports like:

- Tahm Kench
- Nautilus
- Leona

Comment: If you feel I could improve the answer or add to it, please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

for on this question isn't really related to support because for one the support build for the team and 2 their are better armor and and ap item if that what you need you are bying thes item for the active. the question is more which adc is playing with you.

the main issue with zeke atm is it is inefficient. most adc build 70 or 80% crit chance so you are basically wasting 30% crit chance. this mean that rather than giving about 25% extra damage to your adc auto you are giving about 12%. you don't really wan't to give the active to your midlaner since at most it increase the damage by 20% if all his speels have 100% ap scaling which doesn't exist so generallly a lot less 0.2*ap scaling.

their are the new armor pen build for which you  might want to concider zeke like lucian, jhin or miss fortune. but they have tendency to be very spell based and thus less efficient on top of that jhin doesn't crit for 100% and netheir does mf ult.

as for on hit and sheen. crits does not amplify these items

long story short, zeke would be a strong item to help standard ad crit build but they generally build more the 50% crit because the passive on crit item are just good. other builds are sub optimal. you can look into maybe the  armor pen adc or maybe the sheen adc. but i haven't seen it in competitive.